# How to get job id in second worker when calling second worker from first worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq to process the background jobs.

```
class MainWorker
 def perform(from_date, to_date) 
   Rails.logger.info "In MainWorker, job id #{jid}"
   SampleWorker.new.perform(from_date, to_date)
 end
end

class SampleWorker
 def perform(from_date, to_date) 
   Rails.logger.info "In SampleWorker, job id #{jid}"
 end
end
```

I am calling SampleWorker from MainWorker. I get Sidekiq Job id in MainWorker when I print. But I see Job id as nil in SampleWorker when I print.

How to get same job id in SampleWorker from MainWorker without passing as paramter?

Is there any session option available? If Yes, How can I do it?

Comment: How is your `MainWorker` job enqueued? It seems to me the only way `jid` is nil in `Sampleworker` and not in `Mainworker` is that they were enqueued differently. Note: `aync` = typo for `async`?

Comment: @MatthieuLibeer Yes. That's right.  jid is nil in Sampleworker and not in Mainworker. Is there a way to get the jid from MainWorker to SampleWorker with passing as parameter in perform. Also I have update a typo from aync to async

Comment: jid should never be nil inside the perform method.  Something is wrong with your setup.  Are you using Sidekiq::Testing.inline or some other unusual setup?

Comment: @MikePerham  I am calling like SampleWorker.new.perform(from_date, to_date) inside MainWorker.   I am not using Sidekiq::Testing.inline. Do I have to use Sidekiq::Testing.inline If I have to call Sampleworker inside MainWorker?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a SampleWorker job so there's no JID assigned.  To create a SampleWorker job, you must call `perform_async`.  Calling `SampleWorker.new.perform` directly bypasses Sidekiq entirely.